# Приватный метод проверки ввода

Tags: javascript, ооп

Добрый вечер, сделал приватный метод `_isChannelValid(channelNumber)` проверки ввода. Но он выдает ошибку `_isChannelValid is not defined`. Подскажите как правильно сделать приватный метод проверки на ввод чисел от 1 до 99?

```
class TV {
  constructor() {
    this._power = false;
    this._channel = 1;
    this._lastChannel = 1;
  }

  power() {
    if (this._power) {
      this._power = false;
      this._lastChannel = this._channel;
    } else {
      this._power = true;
      console.log(`TV is on. The channel is #${this._channel}`);
    }
    if (this._power) {
      this._channel = 0;
    } else {
      this.selectChannel(this._lastChannel);
    }
  }

  _isChannelValid(channelNumber) {
    const channelCheck = (!Number.isInteger(channelNumber) || channelNumber < 1 || channelNumber > 99);
    return channelCheck;
  }

  selectChannel(channelNumber) {
    if (_isChannelValid(channelNumber)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this._channel = channelNumber;
      console.log(`Switch to channel #${this._channel}`);
    }
    return true;
  }

  info() {
    if (this._power) {
      console.log('TV is on');
    } else {
      console.log('TV is off');
    }
    console.log(`The channel is ${this._channel}`);
  }

}

const tv = new TV();

/*
tv.power();
tv.selectChannel(8);
tv.info;
 */
```

Comment: В текущей спецификации ES6 нет public, protected или private модификаторов к методам и свойствам. Используйте надстройку над JS, например, TypeScript - [Classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). А в вашем классе, как вам уже ответили, ключевое слово this пропущено при вызове метода класса внутри класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (this._isChannelValid(channelNumber)) {

...

tv.info();
```